# Beginner problem / error with ansi-c and gcc under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, path, linker, ansi-c

I am just starting programming ansi c with gcc under ubuntu (9.04). I get following error messages:

**error messages:**

```
main.c:6: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from main.c:9:
/usr/include/libio.h:332: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/libio.h:364: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/libio.h:373: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/libio.h:493: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_IO_sgetn’
In file included from main.c:9:
/usr/include/stdio.h:314: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/stdio.h:682: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fread’
/usr/include/stdio.h:688: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fwrite’
main.c:12: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
```

I assume it is a very simple problem, maybe in the configuration of ubuntu or gcc. I am new to programming under linux as well. I googled for help and went through a [tutorial](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_27.html) but could not find an answer. Thank you!

**code:**

```
/* cheat with the preprocessor to skip over missing lines to attempt
   to duplicate the circumstance of the original code */
#line 9
// #include <some_random_header.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
     printf("TestOutput\n");

     return (0);
    }
```

**command:**

```
~/Documents/projects/Trials$ gcc -Wall -ansi  main.c
```

Comment: simplify first - remove '#include <math.h>', then do a simple gcc main.c - and fix your main please, it should be int main(int argc, char **argv)

Comment: I used "//" to comment lines, which ansi-c does not like. Thank you all for your input!

Comment: so, just out of curiosity, how was anybody supposed to help you with your problem when you didn't even post the code to the real problem?

Comment: so, just out of curiosity, how do you want to help me with sarcasm?

Comment: This is a real issue - which needs to be pointed out so that others can learn from it.  In your case, I note that instead of a 'mea culpa' you choose to attack, not the wisest choice after a mistake such as this.

Comment: @ KevinDTimm, your right, I will take care of it next time.

Comment: I think this question can be rescued as an example of how a less experienced user can be misled by error messages and miss the root cause. I've tried to nudge it in the right direction by adding the offending comment in the sample code, but I'm not positive I've duplicated the actual circumstance. Any takers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you really sure that the code you show is the code you are actually compiling? You get the error:

```
main.c:12: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token
```

but the code doesn't actually have 12 lines in it.

Comment: Nor does it have a `/` token anywhere.

Comment: I commented some lines to have a minimal example. But that turned out to be the problem. Ansi-C does not like "//".

Answer (score 1):

I used "//" to comment lines, which ansi-c does not like.
Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Even though, it was the answer to my problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com ;-)

Comment: +1 to encourage documenting the answer to the actual problem.